# Apache mod_rewrite - unwanted redirect instead of rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an issue with mod_rewrite and I can't seem to solve it. I stripped the example down to the bare bones and I don't understand why a specific rule forces my browser to redirect instead of rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
#if request is for a physical-file OR for one of the language paths - skip (return as-is)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en-US
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#otherwise: rewrite to en-US folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en-US/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I read the documentation very carefully and it seems like this should actually rewrite every call, so `https://example.com/fuBar.html` should actually retrieve the file `/en-US/fuBar.html` from my server - the users browser shouldn't know about it.

What's really happening is that for some reason the browser is **redirected** to `https://example.com/en-US/fuBar.html`. While this does display the correct content, it's just not what I want or what I thought this `RewriteRule` should do. What am I doing wrong?

*add - the .htaccess of the subfolders de and en-US:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: What other directives do you have? Any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories (perhaps at `/en-US/.htaccess`)? You say you've "stripped the example down to the bare bones", however, the directive you've posted will not trigger an external redirect by itself. In fact, without any other rules this will result in an endless rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error response in the browser). (?)

Comment: Presumably you are using `.htaccess`?

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear - I am new at this and didn't know better. I included the full configuration of my root and my subfolders - both use .htaccess

Comment: There is still nothing here that would trigger a "redirect". Make sure you have cleared your browser (and any intermediary) cache(s). Check the network traffic in the browser dev tools - what exactly do you see? What 3xx HTTP status code are you seeing? However, after your update, your example is now inconsistent - whilst you are describing rewriting to `/en-US`, your directive now rewrites to `/de` instead?

Comment: Also, your `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory rewrites requests to `/index.html` in the document root - is that intentional? Or should you be rewriting to `index.html` in the respective language subdirectory? (This looks wrong since the rewrite to the language subdirectory in the root `.htaccess` file is otherwise unnecessary.)

Comment: I edited the inconsistency. Thank your for that tip with /index.html, I will look into that right now

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip with checking the network tab (should have thought of that). Actually there was no redirect happening at all! Rather since I set <base href="/en-US"> somehow my frontend (Angular) seems to have outsmarted me, manipulating the address without me realizing it.
Turns out I don't even need to change the base href, I just need the rewrites. Thank you so much, you made my day! If you turn your tip about checking the network traffic into an answer I will gladly accept it

Comment: You're welcome. You're not the first to think there was an external redirect, overlooking that the front-end (JavaScript) could be manipulating the URL - so this question could help other readers. I've added that as an answer and padded it out a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the code you've posted that would trigger an external "redirect".

Make sure you have cleared your browser (and any intermediary) cache(s) to ensure you are not seeing an earlier/erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect. (301 redirects are cached persistently by the browser.)

Check the "network traffic" in the browser's developer tools to see the precise nature of this *redirect* to see what it redirects from/to, and well as the 3xx HTTP status code of the redirect (if indeed this is an external redirect).

It would seem the front-end (JavaScript/Angular) is *manipulating* the URL in the address bar (there is no redirect). From comments:

> Actually there was no redirect happening at all! Rather since I set `<base href="/en-US">` somehow my frontend (Angular) seems to have outsmarted me, manipulating the address without me realizing it. Turns out I don't even need to change the base href, I just need the rewrites.